# Здравствуйте, существует ли возможность отслеживать события на странице социальной сети с помощью расширения?

Tags: javascript

Есть сайт, на нём я зарегистрирован, когда ко мне приходит сообщение, воспроизводится звук уведомления.
Мне бы хотелось отловить это событие и изменить заголовок вкладки с этим сайтом, что бы я мог сразу отреагировать на сообщение. Возможно ли написать своё расширение в chrome которое отслеживало такое событие и выполняло действия которые я пропишу?

Comment: Если вкратце, https://www.tampermonkey.net/ менеджер пользовательских скриптов, можешь написать свой js-ник и манипулировать отображением на любом сайте как угодно.

Comment: Я так понимаю, мне надо через GM_addValueChangeListener() как то прослушать изменение переменной, что-то сложно мне...